# SSRS - Separate part of a string and return

Tags: reporting-services, expression

I desperately tried to separate a specific part of a string with an Expression (Mid/InStr).

**String: Transfered from 'Doe, John' to '', Transfered from Group 'Customer' to 'Service'**

I need the group value: **Service**

Can anyone help? Is it possible?

Comment: Is it always after the "Transfered from Group"? Is it always in single quotes?

Comment: Is that string all in one column?

Comment: yes it´s always after the "Transfered from Group" and always in single quotes. The string is all in one column. The length of the values can be different.

Comment: If my answer sorted you out, can you click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with a function.

---

#### Example:

[image: screenshot]

---

#### Textbox Expression:

`=Code.GetTransferedGroup(Fields!YourColumnNameHere.Value)`

---

#### Code:

```
Public Function GetTransferedGroup(columnValue As String) As String
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose:      Seperate part of a string
' Example:      =Code.GetTransferedGroup("Transfered from 'Doe, John' to '', Transfered from Group 'Customer' to 'Service'")
' Reference:    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52658830/ssrs-seperate-part-of-a-string-and-return
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Const transferedHeader   As String = "Transfered from Group"
Const transferedTerm     As String = " to "
Dim transferedPart       As Integer
Dim transferedValues     As String

    Try
        transferedPart = InStr(1, columnValue, transferedHeader, vbBinaryCompare)
        transferedValues = Mid(columnValue, transferedPart + Len(transferedHeader) + 1, Len(columnValue) - (transferedPart + Len(transferedHeader)))
        return Replace(Mid(transferedValues, InStr(1, transferedValues, transferedTerm) + Len(transferedTerm), Len(transferedValues) - InStr(1, transferedValues, transferedTerm)), "'", "")

    Catch 
        return "Error"

    End Try

End Function
```

---

#### Report Properties Code:

[image: screenshot]